# how to insert record using parameterized sql?

Tags: vb.net

How to inert records in sql server database using string concatenation  ?

Below is my code using string concatenation and it gives me error as below:

1. cannot insert records in some client computers.
2. cannot insert records to some computer but can search data in
   database.

   ```
         conn.Open()
         Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand
     cmd.CommandText = String.Format("insert into 
     LimoDatabase(Product_Number,Product_Description,Scan_Date,
     Employee_Id,Serial_Number,PCno)values('{0}','{1}','{2}',
     '{3}','{4}','{5}')", txtProdNum.Text, txtProdDscrp.Text, 
       txtScanDate.Text, txtEmpId.Text, 
         txtSerialNum.Text, cmb_PCno.Text)
         Dim AffectedRows As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
           If AffectedRows > 0 Then
                           loaddata()
                           txtSerialNum.Text = ""
                           counter = counter + 1
                           lblCounter.Text = counter
                       End If
                       conn.Close()

                   End If
   ```

Comment: `MsgBox("SERIAL " & txtSerialNum.Text & " COMPLETED!!! "` is written in the catch block. If you are seeing this messagebox that means there is an exception. You need to get the details about that exception by writing it to some logfiles or events. Without knowing what is going wrong solution can not be suggested.

Comment: hi Chetan, i removed the exception to check the error message. as below;  
************** Exception Text **************
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.   it's too long i only copy the first part. it also says to enable the jit debugging but can't figured it out how to do. please help.

Comment: As per the error the issue is with converting string to datetime. The only datetime column I can see is `Scan_Date` and you are getting value for it from `txtScanDate.Text`. So you need to see what value you are entering in `txtScanDate` textbox which is causing issue. Can you share the value which you are entering in 'txtScanDate' textbox?

Comment: Also  You need to use parameterized SQL instead of string concatenation to generate SQL statement. https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx

Comment: i think its my sql code have problem.Create table LimoDAtabase
(
Product_Number nvarchar(20) not null,
Product_Description nvarchar(200) not null,
Scan_Date datetime not null,
Employee_Id nvarchar(9),
Serial_Number nvarchar(25),
PCno nvarchar (4)
)

alter table LimoDatabase add constraint DK_Scan_DAte
Default SYSDATETIME() for Scan_Date

alter table LimoDatabase add constraint Uk_Serial_Number
Unique(Serial_Number)

Comment: txtscanDate i auto enter the datetime as below code:  txtScanDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()

Comment: hi Chetah thanks for suggesting to use parametarized sql now it works. i change my code in insert .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi chetan thanks for suggestion i changed my code in insert using parameterized sql instead of using string. now its works.

i modified my code in insert function as below.

'INSERT RECORD

```
Private Sub insertSerial()
    SQL.AddParam("@productNumber", txtProdNum.Text)
    SQL.AddParam("@productDescription", txtProdDscrp.Text)
    SQL.AddParam("@employee", txtEmpId.Text)
    SQL.AddParam("@serialNumber", txtSerialNum.Text)
    SQL.AddParam("@pcNo", cmb_PCno.Text)

    SQL.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO LimoDatabase (Product_Number,Product_Description,Employee_Id,Serial_Number,PCno,Scan_Date) " & _
                  "VALUES(@productNumber,@productDescription,@employee,@serialNumber,@pcNo,GETDATE());")
    If SQL.HasException(True) Then Exit Sub
    txtSerialNum.Text = ""


End Sub
```

Comment: Are you intending this to stand as an answer or were you trying to update your question? If it's meant to stand as an answer, please indicate *what you've changed* and *why it fixes the problem*. If you were trying to update your question, please use the *edit* function on the question and delete this answer.

Comment: it's my answer Damien . sorry i'm a newbie here in stackoverflow. now i modified it already.